# How to generate a count based on Text data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, pivot

I have the following table:

[image]

I basically want to Pivot the contents of the Status column and generate a count of the 'Issuer/Ticker' column. For example, I want to know for Allison Shenoy, what is the number of "Issuer/Ticker" that are Past Due and that are "Due within 3 months". So, my answer should read for this analyst: Past Due: 11 and Due within 3 months: 8 based on the data above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    assigned_analyst,
    sum(case when status = 'Past Due' then 1 else 0 end) past_due,
    sum(case when status = 'Due within 3 Months' then 1 else 0 end) due_3_month
from mytable
group by assigned_analyst
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me without using Pivot. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To get the counts of Issuer/Ticker based on each analyst and status, try this:

```
SELECT
    [Assigned Analyst]
    ,[Status]
    COUNT(distinct [Issuer/Ticker]) [Count of Issuer/Ticker]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY [Assigned Analyst], [Status]
```

Otherwise, to get the counts for Allison Shenoy only, try this:

```
SELECT
    [Status]
    COUNT(distinct [Issuer/Ticker]) [Count of Issuer/Ticker]
FROM TableName
WHERE [Assigned Analyst] = 'Allison Shenoy'
GROUP BY [Status]
```

Obviously, replace 'TableName' with the actual name of the table

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick but I did want the Status rows to get separated in separate columns and GMB's answer works better. Thanks!